# What does PhpStorm use a local language interpreter for?

Tags: php, node.js, phpstorm

When following guides on how to setup autocompletion in PhpStorm (as well as other features like debugging) a required step is to set a path to the local interpreter corresponding to the language you are running, e.g. I use PHP and Node JS so I often have to configure path e.g. `/usr/bin/php`.
.
All [PhpStorm documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/configuring-local-php-interpreters.html) I have come across shows *how* to configure but they never give an explanation of *why* the IDE needs the intepreter path. 
.
What does PhpStorm use the interpreter for?

Comment: to run php locally i would assume

Comment: You do not need actual interpreter for code completion -- only Language Level so that IDE can mark PHP 5.6 (for example) features as syntax errors if intended language level is for 5.5 (for example).

Comment: Actual PHP Interpreter is used for running your scripts locally .. or executing PHPUnit tests locally or integration with Composer/CodeSniffer/PHPMD/Phing and other similar stuff (in case if you use it). Depending on your tasks, you may work and debug your remote code without having any local PHP interpreter installed/configured.

Comment: yes, I see you once the IDE has access to language it can provide autocompletion, which I would guess it would use regex or doc block parsing to get info for autocomplete, but not necessarily the interpreter itself. So what would be the purpose of needing the interpreter?

Comment: if you want the IDE to be able to run your php it needs the interpreter, if you don't work that way, you don't need to.

Comment: @user4668401 Autocompletion is not handled by PHP. PHP is great for running PHP, but provides no value to the editors ability to markup PHP code. Other autocompletion features are handled through heuristics.

Comment: @LazyOne thanks, that makes sense. So PhpStorm would use it for tasks that involve actually running code. otherwise, the interpreter is not used for providing autocompletion during text editing ?

Comment: In general -- correct. Note that CodeSniffer/PHPMD are tools written in PHP that can help you control your code quality. They do not actually run your PHP code .. but help you with writing *good quality* code. Not code completion by any means .. but something related to writing actual code.